# Make PlaySound non-blocking

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I've been testing sounds and I noticed that `PlaySound` is blocking, i.e. it waits until the sound has finished playing to return.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main()
{
    PlaySound("E:/Downloads/eb_sfx_archive/brainshock.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME);
    std::cout << "this sound is cool";
    Sleep (500);
    std::cout << "\nmeh... not really";
    return 0;
}
```

This code plays the sound, but it waits to output "this sound is cool" until after the sound has finished playing.  How can I make it not do that?

Answer (score 6):

Play the sound asynchronously:

```
PlaySound(L"E:\\Downloads\\eb_sfx_archive\\brainshock.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> The sound is played asynchronously and `PlaySound` returns immediately after beginning the sound. To terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, call `PlaySound` with `pszSound` set to `NULL`.

Comment: Nice catch. Here's the page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx SNDASYNC: "The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns immediately after beginning the sound. To terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL."

Answer (score 4):

Play the sound asynchronously using the flag `SND_ASYNC`.

I.e:

`PlaySound("E:/Downloads/eb_sfx_archive/brainshock.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);`

The `SND_ASYNC` flag causes `PlaySound` to return immediately without waiting for the sound to finish playing.

Also, if you need to stop playing a sound (looped or asynchronous) without playing another sound, use the following statement:

`PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);`

More info and examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757665(v=vs.85).aspx) (Using PlaySound to Loop Sounds) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx) (PlaySound function).

Comment: Bitwise or, not logical or.  `|`, not, `||`.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Yep, totally agree. Sorry!

Comment: This works, but the sound cuts off as soon as the program outputs "meh, not really"

Comment: I suppose it is because the program ends, isn't it?