# How do I stop function if it has already started?

Tags: c++, function, terminate

I'm very new to c++ and still have a lot to learn, here is something I wanted to do for myself:

I tried creating a simple program which would play music (audio file) if user types 'start', and stop the music if user types 'stop' at any time, and it worked using *PlaySound* (from *WinMM.Lib*). I also wanted to add subtitles to start showing line by line synced with music aaand **let user type start/stop at any time**.

I created void text(string x) function which would start along with void music() but I have no idea how to terminate **text()** function when user types 'stop', it only stops music but the text still shows up.

*Note: I used [timercpp](https://github.com/99xt/timercpp) instead of sleep() to let user type at any time. Also, user doesn't have to type 'stop' specifically, it just can't be 'start' and let it be that way for now.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "timercpp.h"
using namespace std;
int music(string x);
void text(string x);
string x;
int main()
{
        do{
            cout<<"Type start / stop..."<<endl;
            cin>>x;
            music(x);
            text(x);
            cin.clear();
        }while(x!="quit");

}
int music(string x)
{
    system("cls");
    if(x=="start"){
    cout<<" Music ON "<<endl;
    PlaySound("*Path*/cpp/audio.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC);
    return 0;
    }
    else{
    cout<<" MUSIC OFF..."<<endl;
    PlaySound(NULL, 0, SND_FILENAME);
    }
}
void text(string x)
{
    if(x=="start"){
    { 
    Timer t = Timer();
    t.setTimeout([&]() 
    {
    cout<<"// I got summer on my mind," << endl;}, 2500);
    t.setTimeout([&]() 
    {
    cout<<"/ Nowhere else though," << endl;}, 7000);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The subject you need to be looking at is *threading*, which is basically a way of allowing your program to do multiple things at once (and to synchronize those different things as well). However it a very big topic, and I'm not really sure it's something you should be looking at as a beginner. You've plenty of other more basic stuff to learn as well.

Comment: I second john, I don't think there is an easy introduction to multithreading, because multithreading isnt easy. However, this seems to achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421313/make-playsound-non-blocking

Comment: the duplicate explains how you can play sound asynchronsously via the windows API. You call `PlaySound` and the function returns immediately, while the sound will continue to play. Later you can call the function again to stop playing the sound

Comment: had it closed as dupe, but reopened, because the proposed dupe (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421313/make-playsound-non-blocking) is only half of the answer....

Comment: So there is nothing I can do at this point? :/